# firebase generating a notification even when no notification code is used

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

the problem is that with my custom receiver which is calling a notification generating method,i am receiving two push notifications and when i comment out the notification generating code i am still getting one notification

the logcat for this single notification is this

```
11-21 15:55:51.091 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000010 pkg=com.lafalafa.android cmp=com.lafalafa.android/com.lafalafa.services.Receiver (has extras) }, receiver=com.lafalafa.services.Receiver@264a8db5
11-21 15:55:51.092 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: BDC-RECEIVER handled : 0 / ReceiverData{intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000010 pkg=com.lafalafa.android cmp=com.lafalafa.android/com.lafalafa.services.Receiver (has extras) } packageName=com.lafalafa.android resultCode=0 resultData=null resultExtras=null}
11-21 15:55:51.094 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000010 pkg=com.lafalafa.android cmp=com.lafalafa.android/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver (has extras) }, receiver=com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver@13e9ac4a
11-21 15:55:51.105 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService@2b2c44d8, flags=0, startId=1
11-21 15:55:51.104 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: BDC-RECEIVER handled : 0 / ReceiverData{intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000010 pkg=com.lafalafa.android (has extras) } packageName=com.lafalafa.android resultCode=-1 resultData=null resultExtras=null}
11-21 15:55:51.105 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: SVC-Creating service: CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@383917bb className=com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService packageName=com.lafalafa.android intent=null}
11-21 15:55:51.105 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: SVC-CREATE_SERVICE handled : 0 / CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@383917bb className=com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService packageName=com.lafalafa.android intent=null}
11-21 15:55:51.105 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: SVC-SERVICE_ARGS handled : 0 / ServiceArgsData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@383917bb startId=1 args=Intent { act=com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT pkg=com.lafalafa.android cmp=com.lafalafa.android/com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService (has extras) }}
11-21 15:55:51.142 17996-23053/com.lafalafa.android D/FA: Logging event (FE): _nr, Bundle[{_o=fcm, _ndt=0, _nmn=say what, _nmt=1479723949, _nmid=4353520786650478530}]
11-21 15:55:51.144 17996-23053/com.lafalafa.android V/FA: Using measurement service
11-21 15:55:51.145 17996-23053/com.lafalafa.android V/FA: Connecting to remote service
11-21 15:55:51.197 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: SVC-Destroying service: com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService@2b2c44d8
11-21 15:55:51.198 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: SVC-STOP_SERVICE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@383917bb
11-21 15:55:51.199 17996-23053/com.lafalafa.android D/FA: Connected to remote service
11-21 15:55:51.200 17996-23053/com.lafalafa.android V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
11-21 15:55:56.310 17996-23053/com.lafalafa.android V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
11-21 15:57:40.117 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000010 pkg=com.lafalafa.android cmp=com.lafalafa.android/com.lafalafa.services.Receiver (has extras) }, receiver=com.lafalafa.services.Receiver@d577497
11-21 15:57:40.117 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: BDC-RECEIVER handled : 0 / ReceiverData{intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000010 pkg=com.lafalafa.android cmp=com.lafalafa.android/com.lafalafa.services.Receiver (has extras) } packageName=com.lafalafa.android resultCode=0 resultData=null resultExtras=null}
11-21 15:57:40.120 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000010 pkg=com.lafalafa.android cmp=com.lafalafa.android/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver (has extras) }, receiver=com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver@178cd684
11-21 15:57:40.129 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: BDC-RECEIVER handled : 0 / ReceiverData{intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000010 pkg=com.lafalafa.android (has extras) } packageName=com.lafalafa.android resultCode=-1 resultData=null resultExtras=null}
11-21 15:57:40.130 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService@3d337aa2, flags=0, startId=1
11-21 15:57:40.129 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: SVC-Creating service: CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@1e6bbe6d className=com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService packageName=com.lafalafa.android intent=null}
11-21 15:57:40.130 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: SVC-CREATE_SERVICE handled : 0 / CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@1e6bbe6d className=com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService packageName=com.lafalafa.android intent=null}
11-21 15:57:40.130 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: SVC-SERVICE_ARGS handled : 0 / ServiceArgsData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@1e6bbe6d startId=1 args=Intent { act=com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT pkg=com.lafalafa.android cmp=com.lafalafa.android/com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService (has extras) }}
11-21 15:57:40.139 17996-24084/com.lafalafa.android D/FA: Logging event (FE): _nr, Bundle[{_o=fcm, _ndt=0, _nmt=1479724060, _nmid=8165985003147150810}]
11-21 15:57:40.140 17996-24084/com.lafalafa.android V/FA: Using measurement service
11-21 15:57:40.141 17996-24084/com.lafalafa.android V/FA: Connecting to remote service
11-21 15:57:40.159 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: SVC-Destroying service: com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService@3d337aa2
11-21 15:57:40.161 17996-17996/com.lafalafa.android D/ActivityThread: SVC-STOP_SERVICE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@1e6bbe6d
11-21 15:57:40.162 17996-24084/com.lafalafa.android D/FA: Connected to remote service
11-21 15:57:40.162 17996-24084/com.lafalafa.android V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
```

i have no clue how this notification is firing up

Answer (score 0):

Is your app in Background?Then you are receiving one (autogenerated) notification from firebase sdk and another from your receiver.

Comment: Maybe that's the issue 
but i don't want the auto-generated notification 
how to avoid that?

Comment: although even when my app was not in background, i am still getting the auto-generated notification

Comment: You can't avoid from firebase console.But from your own server yes u can, send only data payload (data message).

Comment: I don't understand
on the firebase console i am adding title message and a few data payloads
but i am receiving a notification not containing those payloads, that's the auto genarated one
but i dont want that!!!

Comment: read out above article carefully i hope u will get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i finally solved the problem
I basically removed already existing GCM instances from my code and the code now is only sending one message.

I realised it later that we need to migrate from GCM to FCM and not just add FCM on top of it.

Hope this helps!!